# Is it possible to use address you don't own while running ethereum RPC node (using geth)?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, nodes, ethernodes

In other words, you start your own node and then somehow add accounts you don't own (aka - you don't have their private keys)?

I'm asking because I wanted to make my own node exposed via RPC/internet. Then got curious how secure this is...apparently it isn't since someone used exposed RPC to steal millions a while back. Then I started googling and discovered some 'well known' rpc hosts, while looking into 10-20 of them I found one holding ethers worth nearly $200,000!

Fortunately (maybe fortunately??) this account was locked and "personal" was not available, so unless I am wrong this means no one can send transaction? I didn't try given how illegal this will be but I am 99% sure you can't do this with locked account without "personal".

I am rather curious: are these people too smart, too uncautious or what? And even if I use "personal" to lock the account with strong password - what prevents a hacker to try millions of dictionary combinations to guess the password?

Again: my plan is to start geth without "personal" on account which by default will/should be locked so that no one without root/sh access can start geth as unlocked (yeah not really root since I am on windows anyway but similar...).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think in 2019 someone will leave 200K in a server exposed to the internet, perhaps it is a testnet server or a honeypot.

I'd suggest to use a firewall or similar tool if you want to expose RPC your node to the internet.

The geth/parity have some protection but its functionality is limited to block certain calls. If you want more advanced features like ip whitelisting/authorization, DoS attacks prevention you will have to use another application in front of geth/parity.